# Connection between two minimax theorems

Tags: integration, game-theory, maxima-minima, duality-theorems, nash-equilibrium

According to Wikipedia, [Parthasarathy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthasarathy%27s_theorem) is a generalization of [Von Neumann's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem), but I don't see how how this connection is made.
Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: They both swap $\inf,\sup$ in a similar manner. Von Neumann's theorem deals with finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @copper.hat But how exactly Parthasarathy implies of Von Neumann?

Comment: I would guess by choosing $k$ appropriately (split $[0,1]^2$ into $n \times m$ subrectangles with $k$ being constant on the interior of the subrectangles).